# Oppening a new JFrame with a JButton click

Tags: java, swing

I am currently taking a programming class in high school focused on Java. We have started to get into Swing and GUI's and I am really liking creating GUI applications. So my question was:

A program I wrote displays a `JFrame` with two buttons: Continue and Quit. I figured out how to set the quit action to the quit button but now I want to know how I cant create an `ActionListener` and add it to the continue button. When it's clicked, it will display a simple message like "You Did It!".

What I was thinking was to create a method that will create a new `JFrame` with that message. When the continue button is clicked it will call that method and display the message.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Any help would be awesome! Thank You!

Comment: There is simply `JOptionPane` which you may use to simply display a String message. Somewhat like this... `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You did it!");`

Comment: [How to use dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: Also to simply add an actionListener to a button just simply do... `buttonName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You did it!"); }  });`

Comment: [Many, many, many dups](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=opening+new+jframe+from+button+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F).

Comment: Also the obligatory: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636)

Comment: Thanks for the comments I'm actually going to try this right now. :)

Comment: Hey thanks it worked! But now I noticed that joptionpane displays with an OK button is there any way to add an action listener to the OK button or to the joptionpane itself?